# How can I capture a SRT stream?

Tags: python, stream, vlc, capture

I have established an SRT Stream from a Raspberry Pi to my PC.
Everything works fine. I am also able to watch the stream with VLC.
Now I want to capture the stream in Python.

With RTMP and HTTP the command

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("srt://IP:PORT")
frame = cap.read()
```

worked without any problem.

But with SRT, OpenCV does not even try to capture the stream.

What could I do?

**Edit:**

Some more information about my project:
I have a USB Camera connected with my Raspberry Pi and stream this live video over SRT.  I installed SRT from Haivision and created the stream with the following command:

```
./srt-live-transmit udp://:1234 srt://:4201 -v
```

The UDP path is the input of the USB camera.
To watch the stream locally on the Raspberry Pi over ffplay works.
As I said before, to consume the Video on my PC also worked.
With OBS, until now, I was not able to start the stream.

Comment: What does it do instead of trying to capture the stream? What happens?

Comment: It does nothing, like it does not know what it is. With http cv2 trys to establish the connection. It takes about a minute. With SRT it immediately jumps over the comment. Like it does not even try to connect to the raspberry pi.

Comment: I think that OpenCV simply does not support SRT.

Comment: What is the value of `cap` in the case where it works and in the case where it doesn't work?

Comment: It returns a Videocapture element. in that Element is a Queue of IMG's. With cap.read() you can extract the images. When the connection works, one image is in the queue. When the connection fails, the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways:

**1. Use RTSP instead of SRT**
I couldn`t find any data on how to decode SRT in python, and there is an only official library and example codes for C in Haivision in [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/Haivision/srt), so the easiest way is to change the video streaming protocol for RPI.
[There is good example instruction on how to stream video in RTSP from RPI camera.](https://www.instructables.com/IP-Camera-Using-the-Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Home-Surveil/).
Pros: Easy to do.
Cons: Not SRT if it is a requirement.

**2. Use SRT but not Python**
There are documented examples of code to create an SRT client script, but they are in C and I did not find any data about the python library or example code for SRT. But there is a good example in C: [example from Git Haivision](https://github.com/Haivision/srt/blob/master/examples/example-client-nonblock.c)
On the other hand, OpenCV is also a C-based library. As a result, you may start to learn the C language.
Pros: OpenCV and SRT by Haivision are C-based, so it is even better to use C.
Cons: C is hard to learn.

**3. Develop C wrapper for Python**
If you have a friend that can develop in C, then create a client library or even client API for python.
[There is how C wrappers work.](https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/#python-bindings-overview)

Pros: it is easier for you.
Cons: it is not easy for your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered a similar situation and it seems that it is possible in principle.

I've been able to read frames from a local SRT stream using OpenCV from Python with a following setup:

**Python code** (crucial part was `?mode=listener` after the port)

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("srt://:4200?mode=listener")

# read frames as usual
```

**Streaming from a file via ffmpeg**

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.mp4 -f mpegts "srt://127.0.0.1:4200"
```

Why do I say "in principle"? That's because it requires to have a version of ffmpeg that is compatible with SRT (afaik it should be >= 4.4) both on the streaming and the receiving side (in my case OpenCV was using ffmpeg under the hood for video capture).

Luckily enough both parts of my pipeline were conformant during the initial testing on M1 Mac Air:

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
```

```
opencv-python      4.7.0.72
```

When I tried to run the same on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine - neither streaming nor receiving were possible:

**Streaming side**

```
srt://127.0.0.1:4200: Protocol not found
```

**Receiving side**

Immediately returns upon creating a video capture (unlike a "proper" case where it blocks until connection with a streaming side is established), and attempts to read() from it return `ret=False`

**Conclusion**
If you could ensure that both parts have a recent ffmpeg version (potentially by building them from source) - it is possible, but in practice it might be challenging.